# How to create a list with struct for a json in Uniface

Tags: json, struct, uniface

i need to create a json with the programming language uniface. I use a struct to create the json. But i have a problem to create a list with a struct.

See here my example for the list "Children".

Example - JSON:

```
{
    "First Name" : "Barbara",
    "Last Name" :  "Singh",
    "Date of birth" :   { "year" : 1955, "month" : 1, "day" : 23 }, 
    "Married" : true,
    "Children" :  
    [
        {  "Name" : "Martin", "Year of birth" :  1980 },
        {  "Name" : "Margaret", "Year of birth" : 1983 }        
    ],
    "Mobile phone" : null
}
```

Example - Struct:

```
[]
    [First Name] = "Barbara"
    [Last Name]  = "Singh"
    [Date of birth]
        [year] = 1732             
        [month] = 2               
        [day] = 22                
    [Married] = "T"               
    [Children]
        []
             [Name] = "Martin"
             [Year of birth] = 1980      
        []
             [Name] = "Margaret"   
             [Year of birth] = 1983      
     [Mobile phone]
```

Example based on the Uniface documentation: [Structs for JSON Data](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/uniface/10/uniface/proc/structs/transformingWithStructs/structsForJson.htm?tocpath=Scripting%20Application%20Behavior%7CTransforming%20Complex%20Data%20Using%20Structs%7C_____6)

So, how can i create a list with uniface for a json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution based on the post ["How to create a list with struct for a json in Uniface](https://community.rocketsoftware.com/forums/forum-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=fa4597fa-0a2b-4bf4-ace2-00780e08ea42&CommunityKey=edb92b7f-cb45-44f3-9782-c48a111007d6&tab=digestviewer#bmd5d391b9-d88f-4e1c-9a1a-9f9ca74b4d62), which inspired my solution.

Solution:

```
myStructure = $newstruct
myStructure->Children = $newstruct
myStructure->Children->$tags->jsonClass="array"

forlist sRecordPerson, nCounter in sListOfPersons
  sStruktur->Children-><NULL>{nCounter} = $newstruct

  sStruktur->Children-><NULL>{nCounter}->Name = $item("Name", sRecordPerson)
  sStruktur->Children-><NULL>{nCounter}->Yearofbirth = $item("Yearofbirth", sRecordPerson)

endfor
```